# Consistency of EM for missing data in non-parametric setting

Tags: nonparametric, missing-data, expectation-maximization

When we have missing data, a parametric model, and an expectation-maximization procedure, and we want to show that our procedure leads to consistent estimators, we can sometimes set up score functions of our E-step and score functions under complete data and show that these are asymptotically equivalent.  [1, 2] are examples of this, but I've seen this in other settings besides Cox regression as well.

In the non-parametric setting, we have influence functions instead of score functions: is there any literature similar to this for EM procedures, where one shows that E-step influence functions are asymptotically equivalent to the influence functions if the data was known, and from that they deduce consistency?

[1] Pugh, Marian Glynis, J. Robins, S. Lipsitz, and D. Harrington. "Inference in the Cox proportional hazards model with missing covariate data." PhD diss., Harvard School of Public Health, 1993.

[2] Herring, Amy H., and Joseph G. Ibrahim. "Likelihood-based methods for missing covariates in the Cox proportional hazards model." Journal of the American Statistical Association 96, no. 453 (2001): 292-302.